# Controlling output linewidth linestyle using gdal_rasterize shapefile shp to Geotiff

Tags: shapefile, gdal

I have successfully combined a shapefile (.shp) and a GeoTiff using gdal_rasterize.

The shapefile displays as one pixel wide in the GeoTiff, but I need it to be wider and more visible, say, 5 pixels wide and red.

Can anyone suggest an alternate way to achieve this? This needs to run as a script and not use desktop gis software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate a buffer directly with `ogr2ogr` using GDAL >= 1.10 with SQLite and SpatiaLite support. If the raster spatial resolution is e.g. 1m:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT ST_Buffer(geometry,2.5) FROM lines" buffer_lines.shp lines.shp
```

Finally, you can adapt and apply the first example of [`gdal_rasterize`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) documentation:

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -l buffer_lines buffer_lines.shp work.tif
```

Comment: afalciano - I will give this a try! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Once I got the gdal configuration sorted, this worked perfectly.